# Is there any way to open git-bash and send commands in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

```
from tkinter import *
import os


pencere = Tk()
pencere.title("Hello")
pencere.geometry("550x550")
label1 = Label(text="Hallo",font="bold 25")
label1.place(x=150,y=30)

label2 = Label(text="Command")
label2.place(x=5,y=90)

label3 = Entry(width=50)
label3.place(x=50,y=90)

def gitbash():
    os.startfile('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe')

ac = Button(text="Olustur",width=10,height=3,command = cmd)
ac.place(x=100,y=150)


pencere = mainloop()
```

I want to send commands to GitBash from gitbash function. For example I want to send "ls" command, when I open Button, GitBash should be opened and ls command will be sent.

Answer (score 1):

to do that u can use a module called `subprocess`

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("ipconfig", shell=True, capture_output=True)
```

this piece of code will run `ipconfig` and it will run in the shell and the output would also be captured